# Draw a sphere using sectors and stack WebGL

Tags: webgl

I'm trying to draw a sphere using sectors and stacks algorithm but it output nothing and do not know where is the problem. Any help?

I implemented the algorithm literally as written in: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_sphere.html

Everything is working fine except the coloredShpere function

this is a photo of what appears to me when I run this function:

[image]

and you can find the whole code in: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dnnkk1w7oq4O7hPTMeGRkyELwi4tcl5X

```
let mesh = createMesh(gl);

const PI = 3.1415926;
const r = 1.0;
const stackCount = 16;
const sectorCount = 16;

let x : number;
let y : number;
let z : number; 
let xy : number;

let vertices: number[] = new Array();
let normals : number[] = new Array();
let texCoords : number[] = new Array();

let nx: number;
let ny: number;
let nz: number; 
let lengthInv: number;
lengthInv = 1.0 / r;
let s: number;
let t: number;

let sectorStep = 2 * PI / sectorCount;
let stackStep = PI / stackCount;
let sectorAngle : number;
let stackAngle : number;

for(let i = 0; i<=stackCount; i++) {
    stackAngle = PI/2 - i*stackStep; //-90 to +90
    xy = r*Math.cos(stackAngle);
    z = r*Math.sin(stackAngle);

    for(let j = 0; j<=sectorCount; j++) {
        sectorAngle = j*sectorAngle; //0 to 360

        x = xy*Math.cos(sectorAngle);
        y = xy*Math.sin(sectorAngle);
        vertices.push(x);
        vertices.push(y);
        vertices.push(z);

        nx = x * lengthInv;
        ny = y * lengthInv;
        nz = z * lengthInv;
        normals.push(nx);
        normals.push(ny);
        normals.push(nz);

        // vertex tex coord (s, t) range between [0, 1]
        s = j / sectorCount;
        t = i / stackCount;
        texCoords.push(s);
        texCoords.push(t);
    }

}

// generate CCW index list of sphere triangles
// indices
//  k1--k1+1
//  |  / |
//  | /  |
//  k2--k2+1
let indices: number[] = new Array();
let k1 : number;
let k2 : number;
for(let i = 0; i<stackCount; i++) {
    k1 = i * (sectorCount + 1); //frist stack
    k2 = k1 + sectorCount + 1; //second stack
    for(let j = 0; j<sectorCount; j++) {
        //k1, k2, k1+1
        if(i != 0) {
            indices.push(k1);
            indices.push(k2);
            indices.push(k1+1);
        }

        //k1+1, k2, k2+1
        if(i != (stackCount-1)) {
            indices.push(k1+1);
            indices.push(k2);
            indices.push(k2+1);
        }
    }
}

mesh.setBufferData("positions", new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
//mesh.setBufferData("colors", new Uint8Array(), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
mesh.setElementsData(new Uint32Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

//mesh.setBufferData("colors", new Uint8Array(), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
return mesh;
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: Learn how to use [`console.log`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/log) and your browser's [debugger](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript)

I didn't check if your code actually works or not but I did add these lines at the bottom of what you posted above

```
console.log(vertices);
console.log(indices);
```

and what I saw was

[image: NaNs]

All those `NaN` values are clearly wrong

Stepping through the code comes to this line

```
sectorAngle = j*sectorAngle; //0 to 360
```

which is where the `NaN` is generated

[image]

which doesn't match the article you linked to

```
sectorAngle = j * sectorStep;           // starting from 0 to 2pi
```

Whether or not that's the only issue I don't know but if there are more then use `console.log` and the debugger to help find the issue. One way to make the code easier to debug is set `stackCount` and `sectorCount` to something small like 4 and 2 respectively and then you should have some idea what all the values should be and you can compare with what values you are getting.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I noticed so I edited the code and it finally worked!

Answer (score 0):

If someone interested to know the solution, this is the code after some improvements: 
`

```
let mesh = createMesh(gl);
const PI = 3.1415926;
const r = 1.0;

let vertices = [];
let colors  = [];

for(let i = 0; i<=verticalResolution; ++i) {
    let theta = i * Math.PI / verticalResolution; //-90 to 90
    let sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
    let cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);

    for(let j = 0; j<=horizontalResolution; ++j) {
        let phi = j * 2 * Math.PI / horizontalResolution; //0 to 360
        let sinPhi = Math.sin(phi);
        let cosPhi = Math.cos(phi);

        let x = sinTheta*cosPhi;
        let y = cosTheta;
        let z = sinTheta*sinPhi;

        vertices.push(r*x);
        vertices.push(r*y);
        vertices.push(r*z);

        colors.push((x+1)/2*255);
        colors.push((y+1)/2*255);
        colors.push((z+1)/2*255);
        colors.push(255);
    }

}

// generate CCW index list of sphere triangles
// indices
//  k1--k1+1
//  |  / |
//  | /  |
//  k2--k2+1
let indices = [];
for(let i = 0; i<verticalResolution; ++i) {
    for(let j = 0; j<horizontalResolution; ++j) {
        let first = (i * (horizontalResolution + 1)) + j;
        let second = first + horizontalResolution + 1;

        indices.push(first);
        indices.push(second);
        indices.push(first+1);

        indices.push(second);
        indices.push(second+1);
        indices.push(first+1);
    }
}

mesh.setBufferData("positions", new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
mesh.setBufferData("colors", new Uint8Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
mesh.setElementsData(new Uint32Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
return mesh;`
```

[Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gahxu.png)